# Cannot access machine via DNS in the private network

Tags: networking

I have a machine in my private network with IP 192.168.1.10
I have a DNS name, "toto.mydns.com", a DNS client is running on the machine.
I configured the router for Port forwarding.
I can access the machine when i am outside my home, when using a pulic IP address it works but when i am at home and i get a dynamic IP address trough DHCP from my router, i cannot use toto.mydns.com anymore, i must use 192.168.1.10 to access.

I would like to know if i need to configure something on the router for that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on `Super User`.

Answer (score 0):

`toto.mydns.com` will resolve to your external public IP
There will almost certainly be nothing routing that IP through to your router, and thus through NAT to your internal address.

The easiest way to resolve this (Pun very much intended) is to have a hosts file entry on your computers running inside your network so that they resolve the same DNS address to the internal address.

A much harder, but more fun, way would be to set up your own DNS server inside your network, have the DHCP dish it out as the primary DNS server for your network and put in an entry for your internal address :D

Have fun...

Answer (score 0):

Toto.mydns.com is accessible from outside,this DNS is assigned on a machine with a static IP address(sorry not dynamic),so the IP of this machine is 192.168.1.10.
Whrn i am at home in my private network i need to enter 192.168.1.10 and toto.mydns.com does not work.Any help???